# How to Django models filefield parametric storage?

Tags: python, django

**My code:**

```
from django.db import models
from private_storage.fields import PrivateFileField
from private_storage.storage import private_storage
from aratarikan_com.settings import public_storage


class File(models.Model):

    published = models.BooleanField()

    @property
    def storage(self):
        if self.published == True:
            return public_storage
        elif self.published == False:
            return private_storage

    file = PrivateFileField(storage=storage)
```

**ValueError:** *Cannot serialize: 
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
For more, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing*

**You must understand what I want to do. Does anyone have an idea?**

Comment: You can't do that, for a whole load of reasons. I *think* what you want is to customise access based on an attribute, which you do in the view, not the model, by defining `can_access_file` - see [the docs](https://github.com/edoburu/django-private-storage#retrieving-files-by-object-id).

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I guess I will have to look for other ways.